# How to speed up compass watch rendering?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

The Title says pretty much everything but add more details lets say I have compass project importing many partials files and modules such as sassy-button some partials and modules import themselves other partials or the same one (just to make sure dependencies are always imported someway).

The matter for me here is to speed up the css generation when watching my project for modifications.

Here is how looks my sass project :

```
modules/
  css3/
  sassy-buttons/
  _sassy-buttons.scss
  _fancyselect.scss
partials/
  _base.scss
  _typography.scss
  _resetHtml5.scss
  _form.scss
  _ui.scss
  _layout.scss
  _header.scss
  _main-menu.scss
  _variables.scss
config.rb
screen.scss
print.scss
activity.scss
testimonials.scss
default.scss
```

And here is the content of the config.rb file :

```js
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "../../../../../web/static/css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "img"
http_images_path = "/static/img"
generated_images_dir = "img"
generated_images_path = "../../../../../web/static/img"
http_generated_images_path = "/static/img"

javascripts_dir = "js"
fonts_dir = "font" 
http_fonts_path = "/static/font"

line_comments = true
output_style = ":expanded"
```

Comment: changing the output style to compressed and turning line comments off might help a little bit. I see you have images and generated images dir, are you spriting? if you are that is most likely the slowest part of your process. Take a look at how you are doing that and see if you are spriting the same image multiple times.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not spriting automatically at this point (exactly because I read it might slow down considerably the rendering) I just prepared the project to do so in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up your sprite generation by installing a C extension called **oily_png** that runs faster than the default ruby extension **chunky_png**. Just install via command line: `gem install oily_png`. Compass will use it automatically.

Comment: Thanks @danny I'll give it a try. My question was more about what "else" could be done, because even before implementing spritting I had some serious delay when recompilling the entire project or modules used often as dependencies in other partials. If you have any idea about it would be welcome